# Get Azure Active Directory password expiry date in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I am working with Azure Active Directory and want to know when a user's password expires.

Currently I use these PowerShell commands to connect to msol service successfully and get password expiry, but I'm not quite sure how to get password expiry date.

I am using Azure Active Directory PowerShell module.

```
Connect-MsolService
    Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName 'Username' | Select PasswordNeverExpires
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for the `LastPasswordChangeTimestamp` attribute:

```
Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName 'Username' |Select LastPasswordChangeTimestamp
```

This only tells you when the password was last changed, not when it will expire, so grab the password validity from the Password Policy as well:

```
$PasswordPolicy = Get-MsolPasswordPolicy
$UserPrincipal  = Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName 'Username'

$PasswordExpirationDate = $UserPrincipal.LastPasswordChangeTimestamp.AddDays($PasswordPolicy.ValidityPeriod)
```

`$PasswordExpirationDate` should now have the timestamp for when the password expires

Comment: looking for, when current password expires attribute.

Comment: @MandarJogalekar No such attribute exists, you'll have to calculate it. Answer updated

Comment: only one change to the answer  $UserPrincipal.LastPasswordChangeTimestamp.AddDays($PasswordPolicy.ValidityPeriod)

Comment: @MandarJogalekar My apologies, I thought the `ValidatyPeriod` property was a `TimeSpan`. I've updated the answer

Comment: I noticed also that get-msolpasswordpolicy command does not work if user is not assigned global admin role .. it's not real to assign every user global admin .. any way around it?

Answer (score 1):

What Mathias R.Jessen said was correct.

But, you may get inaccurate data in some cases like When a tenant has multiple domains (Each domain can have different password policy), when 'Password never expires' set for individual users and if 'password never expires' set through Password policy.

Below code will help you to get the correct result.

```html
$Domains=Get-MsolDomain   #-Status Verified 
foreach($Domain in $Domains) 
{  
  $PwdValidity=(Get-MsolPasswordPolicy -DomainName $Domain).ValidityPeriod 
  $PwdPolicy.Add($Domain.name,$PwdValidity) 
}  
Get-MsolUser -All | foreach{ 
 $UPN=$_.UserPrincipalName 
 $PwdLastChange=$_.LastPasswordChangeTimestamp 
 $UserDomain= $UPN -Split "@" | Select-Object -Last 1  
 $PwdValidityPeriod=$PwdPolicy[$UserDomain] 
}
```

You can download the script from Microsoft's technet gallery: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Export-Office-365-Users-91b4fc50