# How to get password policy for Azure Active Directory logged in user

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I want to get password expiry date of logged in user in c# using graph api or adal.

With this question, I know how to get the password policy and also the expiry date using PowerShell but not yet sure with C#

[Get Azure Active Directory password expiry date in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43294517/)

In c# Either I want to Get PasswordExpiry Date or as an Alternative LastPasswordChangedDate.

Using AD Graph API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get this property of Azure AD user using C#, we can call the PowerShell commands directly. You can refer the code sample below to achieve the goal:

```
private static void GetPasswordExpiredDate()
{
    try
    {
        var userName = "";
        var password = "";
        var securePassword = new SecureString();
        var domainName = "";
        foreach (char c in password)
        {
            securePassword.AppendChar(c);
        }

        Collection<PSObject> user = null;
        Collection<PSObject> passwordPolicy = null;
        // Create Initial Session State for runspace.
        InitialSessionState initialSession = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
        initialSession.ImportPSModule(new[] { "MSOnline" });
        // Create credential object.
        PSCredential credential = new PSCredential(userName, securePassword);
        // Create command to connect office 365.
        Command connectCommand = new Command("Connect-MsolService");
        connectCommand.Parameters.Add((new CommandParameter("Credential", credential)));
        // Create command to get office 365 users.
        Command getPasswordPolicy = new Command("Get-MsolPasswordPolicy");
        getPasswordPolicy.Parameters.Add(new CommandParameter("DomainName", domainName));
        //Command getUserCommand = new Command("$UserPrincipal=Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName 'user1@adfei.onmicrosoft.com'");
        Command getUserCommand = new Command("Get-MsolUser");
        getUserCommand.Parameters.Add(new CommandParameter("UserPrincipalName", "user1@adfei.onmicrosoft.com"));
        //Command getPasswordExpiredDate = new Command("$UserPrincipal.LastPasswordChangeTimestamp.AddDays($PasswordPolicy.ValidityPeriod)");

        using (Runspace psRunSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(initialSession))
        {
            // Open runspace.
            psRunSpace.Open();
            //Iterate through each command and executes it.
            foreach (var com in new Command[] { connectCommand, getUserCommand, getPasswordPolicy })
            {
                var pipe = psRunSpace.CreatePipeline();
                pipe.Commands.Add(com);
                if (com.Equals(getUserCommand))
                    user = pipe.Invoke();
                else if (com.Equals(getPasswordPolicy))
                    passwordPolicy = pipe.Invoke();
                else
                    pipe.Invoke();
            }
            DateTime date =(DateTime) user[0].Properties["LastPasswordChangeTimestamp"].Value;
            UInt32 ValidityPeriod = (UInt32)passwordPolicy[0].Properties["ValidityPeriod"].Value;
            Console.WriteLine($"The password will be expired at {date.AddDays(ValidityPeriod)}");
            // Close the runspace.
            psRunSpace.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, in order to get password expiry from "LastPasswordChangeTImeStamp" i need to get MSOL password policy.however user has to be "Global Admin" to be able to retrieve password policy which is not realistic. How can i work around this?

Comment: To workaround this issue, you can create a service using the admin account as a proxy. And you can add the authentication/authorization for the service based on  your own requirement.

Comment: @MandarJogalekar Please feel free to let me know if you still have the problem about this issue.

Comment: Hello,
I am not sure it's possible for us to maintain the kind of script with admin username and passwords to fetch information.

Also I am using Azure AD graph client, and I cannot get "PasswordLastChangedTimeStamp" which I can access through powershell. It will be okay also, If I can get Logged in user's LastPasswordChanged Timestamp in c#.

Comment: The Azure AD Graph doesn't support this property if you want the Azure AD Graph to support this feature, you can submit the [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory) from here. The code above is corresponding to that you used the PowerShell  script, and it can retrieve this property well. Would you mind sharing the concern of this piece of code?

Comment: thanks, above code will get me LastPasswordChangedTimestamp but I want to know passwordexpirydate of the user.

Comment: To get the password expired date, we just only to using the PowerShell command in your previews thread answered by Mathias R. Jessen. I also update the code in the post, please let me know if it helps.

Comment: I think Any normal AD user cannot get Password-Policy, it has to be "Global Admin",(This I also tested in powershell) I want to run this in Azure App Service for many AD Users who will never be in Admin role.

Comment: @MandarJogalekar This is limited by the Azure AD for the security reason. As I mentioned in the first comment, if you want to break this limitation, you need to publish a service as a workaround. And in the service, you need to use the admin account to connect to Azure AD.