# Connect-Msolservice error after publishing the code to Azure Web App

Tags: c#, powershell, azure-web-app-service

I was developing an Asp.Net web application that will execute particular PowerShell Commands for Office 365. The code contains two parts of the commands (Exchange Online and MSOnline Command). The code is working fine locally on my PC. But When I published the code into Azure Web App the Exchange Online Commands are working as I expected it, but MSOnline commands are giving the below error:

> The term 'Connect-MsolService' is not recognized as the name of a
>   cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling
>   of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is
>   correct and try again.

I am sure that this error has raised because it did not find the matched MSOnline dlls files to import the module. I have added the dll's using Kudo but also the same. anyone have any idea how to solve this one.

Thank you always

Answer (score 0):

Doing some reading [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/835e869b-ed54-4672-9818-cb9b0a5fc72e/how-to-install-windows-powershell-microsoft-online-services-signin-assistant-and-microsoft-online?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43658556/connect-to-azure-ad-using-powershell-commands-from-azure-app-service), it looks like you aren't allowed to install the prerequisites needed unless you upgrade (the answer in that second link describes that).

I have had to do this too: call PowerShell from C# for Office 365 administration, so I feel your pain :) although we host on a normal Windows server.

Comment: If you are to run it in Azure, you could go for an azure automation account, which can be invoked with a https get / post.

Comment: Thank you @GabrielLuci for your comment, did you finalize MSOnline using azure because based on the links you provided it tells that I need to install the package on a Windows Server and publish it from there.

Comment: I did not use Azure, no. Publishing on a Windows server is one option. But it looks like it's just your Azure subscription that prevents installing the prerequisites.

Comment: Basically, you need to be able to install the [sign-in assistant](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=28177) and run `Install-Module MSOnline`. If you haven't done that yet, try it and see what happens.

Comment: The thing is I cannot install an app on web app service on Azure.

Comment: Right, so that means you can't do it. That [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43672793/1202807) says you need "Cloud Service or Virtual Machine" to install what you need.

Comment: Thank you Gabriel. That means that I should install it on Azure Windows Server VM. Do you know what are the prerequisites that I need to install on the server so I can be able to run my code.

Comment: It's documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/enterprise/powershell/connect-to-office-365-powershell#connect-with-the-microsoft-azure-active-directory-module-for-windows-powershell), but it's exactly what I listed above (the sign-in assistant and the MSOnline module).

Comment: I have created a clear Windows Server VM and hosted my app in IIS trying to publish it but during the login screen I am getting the below error: [outlook.office365.com] Connecting to remote server outlook.office365.com failed with the following error message : Access is denied. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.