# Graph API to get Password expiry

Tags: c#, adal, azure-ad-msal

From few days I struggling with one issue with ADAL/MSAL Graph API implementation for getting user password expiry date. I tried below code,

```
var authContext = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext(ADsettings.AADInstance + ADsettings.Tenant);

var clientCred = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.ClientCredential(ADsettings.AppTokenClientID, ADsettings.ClientSecret);

Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationResult resulttoken = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(ADsettings.ResourceId, clientCred);
```

But fortunately, that didn't work, because "resulttoken.UserInfo" was returned with null value. 
I also tried to use user info end point through open id apis.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/ceppr.onmicrosoft.com/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

Openid User info end point api is below,

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/87268ca1-*************************9cf131cc33ac/openid/userinfo
```

but that also didn't work for me.
I need your help to retrieve password expiry date from Azure AD. Please
 provide some input or solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You cannot get the password expiry date from "resulttoken.UserInfo".

Firstly, you should be unable to get userinfo from the token. Secondly, even if you get userinfo, you won't get the password expiry date.

I don't think we can get it via Microsoft Graph API currently.

The related information can only be got from Powershell.

You can use `Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName 'Username' |Select LastPasswordChangeTimestamp` to get `LastPasswordChangeTimestamp`, which means the time when this Azure AD user last changed their password.

Then you need to grab the password validity from the Password Policy:

```
$PasswordPolicy = Get-MsolPasswordPolicy
$UserPrincipal  = Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName 'Username'

$PasswordExpirationDate = $UserPrincipal.LastPasswordChangeTimestamp.AddDays($PasswordPolicy.ValidityPeriod)
```

You can refer to a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43294517/get-azure-active-directory-password-expiry-date-in-powershell).

Answer (score 2):

You can consider using the following Graph API call;

**Request:**

**GET** `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{userPrincipalName}?$select=displayName,lastPasswordChangeDateTime`

**Response:**

```
{

    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#users(displayName,lastPasswordChangeDateTime)/$entity",

    "displayName": "User 1",

    "lastPasswordChangeDateTime": "2017-11-09T07:29:09Z"

}
```

You can find details about this [here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-beta#properties)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Now for 1.0 Graph version it also requires a request header ConsistencyLevel : eventual